# Public property of private class

Tags: c#

I have a NavigationModel class which implements site navigation. Internally there is a private implementation of NavigationNode which I want to be able to declare within the NavigationModel but not outside of it. How would I accomplish this? When I do the following:

```
public class NavigationModel
{
    public List<NavigationNode> NavigationNodes { get; set; }
    public NavigationModel()
    {

    }

    private class NavigationNode
    {

    }
}
```

The property tells me:

> Inconsistent accessibility: property type
>   'List' is less accessible than
>   property 'NavigationModel.NavigationNodes'

Comment: Why not just make the property private? Put it this way: it makes no sense to any code outside the NavigationModel, so how were you intending to use it?

Comment: If NavigationNodes is intended to be used within NavigationModel only then why mark it as public? If its meant to be used publically then just make NavigationNode public

Comment: NavigationNodes will be used to dynamically build the nav menu in the view.

Comment: that doesn't answer the questions above. The point of the questions was to ask whether you ever intend to use NavigationNodes _outside_ your NavigationModel class.

Comment: I intend to use properties of NavigationNode to display in the view and so I need access to those properties. I want to be able to consume navigation nodes within the application but not declare them outside of NavigationModel.

Comment: You are using the verb "declare" in a way I don't recognize; can you give me an example of what you mean by "declaring them outside"?

Comment: There is a larger problem with this design; is it really the case that you want any user of the model to be able to (1) add or remove nodes from the list of nodes, or (2) replace the list with null, or an entirely different list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is raised because by declaring `NavigationModel` as public, you create a public interface that is used to access NavigationModel. Part of this interface are the signatures of the public methods or properties. By that, you'd publish class `NavigationNode` that is supposed to be private - hence the error.

In order to fix this, you could create a public interface that only contains the parts of `NavigationNode` that you want to publish. If you do not want to publish anything, the interface is empty. The following sample shows the basic components:

- Public interface `INavigationNode`.
- Property of type `List<INavigationNode>`.
- Private class `NavigationNode` that implements the interface.

---

```
public interface INavigationNode 
{
  // Add parts of NavigationNode that you want to publish
}

public class NavigationModel
{
    public List<INavigationNode> NavigationNodes { get; set; }
    public NavigationModel()
    {

    }

    private class NavigationNode : INavigationNode
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: This is the answer however I still can't do this because I am doing a JsonConvert.Deserialize of my object which can't use an interface so I had to just make my NavigationNode class public.

Answer (score 0):

NavigationNode needs to be public for this to work properly. Making it public still keeps the declaration internal to the containing class NavigationModel yet classes outside NavigationModel can reference it.